# How to put image in both <ion-header> and <ion-content> in Ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm currently developing Ionic app and stuck at implementing image in both ion-header and ion-content.

Here's screenshot how I implemented.
As you can see from screenshot, ion header and ion-content contents are hidden because I set image `z-index` to high number;

[image]

Could anyone please suggest how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way to do that, and it's by using the `fullscreen` property from the `ion-content` component ([docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#properties)). So the trick is to make the content to be fullscreen and then to set the background of the header to be transparent so that it doesn't cover the background.

### Template:

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding" fullscreen>
  ...
  ...
</ion-content>
```

### Styles:

```
ion-toolbar {
  --ion-toolbar-background: transparent;
}

ion-content {
  --background: url('/assets/your_image.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

---

**Important:** There's currently an issue that makes the backgroung image to flicker in some specific scenarios ([Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17494)). If this issue affects your app, the recommended workaround is to set the background in the component instead of by using css like this:

### Template:

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<!-- The only change is the id added to the ion-content -->
<ion-content id="my-page-content" class="ion-padding" fullscreen>
  ...
  ...
</ion-content>
```

### Styles:

```
ion-toolbar {
  --ion-toolbar-background: transparent;
}

ion-content {
  // Do not set the background here!
}
```

### Component:

```
import { DomController } from '@ionic/angular';

// ...

@Component({...})
export class MyPage { 

  constructor(private domController: DomController) {}

  // ...

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.initializeBackground();
  }

  // ...

  private initializeBackground(): void {
    try {
      const content = document.querySelector('#my-page-content');
      const innerScroll = content.shadowRoot.querySelector('.inner-scroll');

      this.domController.write(() => {
        innerScroll.setAttribute(
          'style',
          'background: url("/assets/img/your_image.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover',
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, Btw the problem is that as you can see from my screenshot, app contains 2 white mask images (one in the top-left and one in the top-right), Those images should be fixed size and screen should be responsive. Any thought on this?

Comment: @SvetoslavAtanasov I think you can use some elements with [fixed conten](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#fixed-content) for that. 

Could you please create a stackblitz project with those images so I can reproduce the issue and see how to solve it?