# Ionic / Capacitor flickering screen and refresher not working

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am developing an app, and it works 100% in android. In IOS I have 2 issues:

1. refresher does not work

   <ion-refresher slot="fixed" @ionRefresh="doRefresh($event)">
2. there is a flicker when I touch the screen (may be related to background? I read some old posts about that)

   ion-content.background{
   --background: url(/bg.png) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
   }

I don't believe its relevant to this issue, but I am using vuejs.

I tested in various desktop browsers and it works as well.

Comment: If you run your app in Safari does it behave the same?

Comment: safari in Mac everything is OK, safari in iPhone same as app, with same issues

Comment: So this is probably an issue with that refresh component. What version of ionic and capacitor are you using? You can run `ionic info` if you're using the cli.

Comment: Ionic Framework : @ionic/vue 5.6.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.7
BTW, I tried on local network in IOS Safari browser, same issue. 

I noticed this in documentation: "Using the iOS native ion-refresher requires setting the pullingIcon property on ion-refresher-content to the value of one of the available spinners"

so it can't be blank like it is in docs?

Comment: pullingIcon="arrow-down" < so it seems this fixed it. Only remaining issue is the flickering screen on IOS

It seems the flickering has happened before, found this on stackoverflow, will test and report: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159372/background-image-flickering-with-user-interaction-on-ios-ionic-5

Answer (score 0):

So, we had 2 things here, and I thank @johnborges for following up

1. it was necessary to add the pullingIcon
   [link for Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher)
   and the relevant paragraph

> Using the iOS native ion-refresher requires setting the pullingIcon
> property on ion-refresher-content to the value of one of the available
> spinners. See the Spinner Documentation for accepted values. The
> pullingIcon defaults to the lines spinner on iOS. The spinner tick
> marks will be progressively shown as the user pulls down on the page.

2. the flicker, based on this link [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159372/background-image-flickering-with-user-interaction-on-ios-ionic-5) I added a CSS DIV element instead of styling ion-content. It worked. I had to do a secodn CSS trick because one of my pages had fullpage slides and padding, but after that it worked